# Will the max heap size per-process be increased if OS gets updated?

Tags: android

For example, the original OS version of Nexus One is 2.1 and it has 24MB as the max heap size per-process. 
Now, if I update the Android OS of Nexus One to 2.3.3, will its max heap size per-process increased to 32MB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is specific to manufacturer, device and OS version. AFAIK there is no rule says it should increase. If infrastructure supports, they may increase.